# Making a dropdown to be reusable as single or multiple mode

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using `vue-select` and my making own component on top of it (not sure if that is good practise):

```js
//SelectInput.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <label
      v-if="label"
      class="block text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-700 uppercase"
      :for="id"
      >{{ label }}</label
    >
    <v-select :options="options" v-bind:multiple="multiple">
      <slot/>
    </v-select>

    <div v-if="errors.length" class="form-error">{{ errors[0] }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import vSelect from 'vue-select'
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';

export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  components: {
    vSelect
  },
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      default() {
        return `select-input-${this._uid}`;
      }
    },
    value: [String, Number, Boolean],
    label: String,
    errors: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    multiple: {
      type: String,
      default: "false"
    },
    extraClass: Array,
    options: Array
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: this.value
    };
  },
  watch: {
    selected(selected) {
      this.$emit("input", selected);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    focus() {
      this.$refs.input.focus();
    },
    select() {
      this.$refs.input.select();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I am calling this in pages such as:

```js
//Create.vue

//This should only allow single select
<select-input v-model="form.tab" extraClass="block w-full transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" label="Activity Tab" :options="outletOptions"/>

//This should have multiple select
<select-input v-model="form.tags" extraClass="block w-full transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" label="Visual Tags" :options="tagOptions" :multiple="true"/>
```

At the moment, it is giving both select input multiple mode, how can I make it that the `Activity Tab` to be single mode, while the `Visual Tags` to be  multiple?

Comment: Make your `multiple` prop a `Boolean` type, not `String`, eg `multiple: { type: Boolean, default: false }`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes. The problem is that the string `"false"` is _truthy_ as far as Boolean evaluation goes

Comment: Yep, that solved it, thank you very much!